# Insert with object as key fails to compile?

Tags: c++, stl

I'm having trouble getting something to compile.  I don't understand the error thrown out
by the compiler.  Some code to illustrate the problem is below.

```
#include <map>

using namespace std;

class Thing
{
public:
    Thing(int n):val(n) {}

    bool operator < (const Thing& rhs) const
    {
        return val < rhs.val;
    }

    int getVal() { return val; }

private:
    int val;
};


int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    std::map<Thing, int> mymap;
    Thing t1(1);
    Thing t2(10);
    Thing t3(5);

    mymap[t1] = 1; // OK

    mymap.insert(t1); // Compile error
}
```

Now the compiler error message:

> test.cpp: In function ‘int main(int,
>   char**)’: test.cpp:34: error: no
>   matching function for call to
>   ‘std::map,
>   std::allocator > >::insert(Thing&)’
>   /usr/include/c++/4.4/bits/stl_map.h:499:
>   note: candidates are:
>   std::pair,
>   std::_Select1st >, _Compare, typename _Alloc::rebind >::other>::iterator, bool> std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare,
>   _Alloc>::insert(const std::pair&) [with _Key = Thing, _Tp = int, _Compare = std::less,
>   _Alloc = std::allocator >]
>   /usr/include/c++/4.4/bits/stl_map.h:539:
>   note:                 typename
>   std::_Rb_tree<_Key, std::pair, std::_Select1st >, _Compare, typename _Alloc::rebind >::other>::iterator std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare,
>   _Alloc>::insert(typename std::_Rb_tree<_Key, std::pair, std::_Select1st >, _Compare, typename _Alloc::rebind >::other>::iterator, const std::pair&) [with
>   _Key = Thing, _Tp = int, _Compare = std::less, _Alloc =
>   std::allocator >]

What does that mean?  Is there another method or operator I need to define in Thing to make it compile?

Comment: The `getVal()` method might be `const`-qualified too.

Comment: @ArunSaha - thanks, it's just an example though.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need `mymap.insert(std::pair<Thing,int>(t1,x));`, where `x` is the value you want to map to `t1`.

Comment: Yup.  Or `mymap.insert(std::make_pair(t1,x));` or `mymap.insert(std::map<Thing,int>::value_type(t1,x))`.  That last one gets more useful if you have a `typedef` for `std::map<Thing,int>`.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot insert a key (Thing object) by itself - `map::insert` (on your map at least) take a `std::pair<Thing,int>` so that you insert value `int` indexed by key `Thing`.

However - it looks to me like you actually want to use `std::set<Thing>`, since your Thing object has its own ordering semantics. Repeating the encapsulated `int val` as the value in a map keyed by `Thing` is redundant, and breaks the nice encapsulation you have here.

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    std::set<Thing> myset;
    Thing t1(1);
    Thing t2(10);
    Thing t3(5);

    std::pair<std::set<Thing>::iterator, bool> result = myset.insert(t1);

    std::set<Thing>::iterator iter = myset.find(t1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`std::map::insert` expects you to pass it a key-value pair.

`mymap.insert(std::pair<Thing, int>(t2, 10));` would work.